# ansible loop hash, 'item' is undefined

Tags: ansible

I am trying to initialise and format multiple disks. below is my code

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Initialize a disk
    community.windows.win_initialize_disk:
      disk_number: "{{ item.disk_number }}"
  - name : Create drive letter "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
    community.windows.win_partition:
      drive_letter: "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
      partition_size: -1
      disk_number: 1
  - name: Format the disk and assign the label
    community.windows.win_format:
      drive_letter: "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
      file_system: NTFS
      new_label: "{{ item.new_label }}"
      full: no
    loop:
      - { disk_number: 0, drive_letter: 'D', new_label: 'temp'}
      - { disk_number: 1, drive_letter: 'E', new_label: 'data'}
      - { disk_number: 2, drive_letter: 'F', new_label: 'logs'}
      - { disk_number: 3, drive_letter: 'G', new_label: 'misc'}
```

I have followed the loop doco https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items to iterate over a hash but I get the error ""msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\n"

how can I get around this? cheeers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your loop is only defined for the last task in the playbook. the first and second task do not have a loop defined. You can define the same loop for each task, or use a block with a loop, like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: create windows partitions
      block:
        - name: Initialize a disk
          community.windows.win_initialize_disk:
            disk_number: "{{ item.disk_number }}"
        - name : Create drive letter "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
          community.windows.win_partition:
            drive_letter: "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
            partition_size: -1
            disk_number: 1
        - name: Format the disk and assign the label
          community.windows.win_format:
            drive_letter: "{{ item.drive_letter }}"
            file_system: NTFS
            new_label: "{{ item.new_label }}"
            full: no
      loop:
        - { disk_number: 0, drive_letter: 'D', new_label: 'temp'}
        - { disk_number: 1, drive_letter: 'E', new_label: 'data'}
        - { disk_number: 2, drive_letter: 'F', new_label: 'logs'}
        - { disk_number: 3, drive_letter: 'G', new_label: 'misc'}
```

Edit:

if you want to be more dynamic, you can put the disk data under `vars:` or in a extra yml-file.

```
disks:
  - disk_number: 0
    drive_letter: D
    new_label: temp
  - disk_number: 1
    drive_letter: E
    new_label: data
```

then change the loop definition to:

```
loop: "{{ disks }}"
```

or

```
loop:
  - "{{ disks }}"
```

if you put the disk-data yaml-block in a yml-file with the name `my_winserver_disks.yml` you can load this yml-file with the `-e` and the @-sign:

```
ansible-playbook -l mywinserver create_disks_playbook.yml -e @my_winserver_disks.yml
```

#### links

You will find more informations about loops here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

If you need to do something like this in linux, have a look at https://github.com/ogaida/playbooks

Comment: that didnt work. I get the error "loop is not a valid attribute for a block". but adding the loop to each task worked. how can I make the playbook accept the hash that is in the loop as inputs? I want the user to be able to add X number of disks. thanks

Comment: I have edit the answer. The error "loop is not a valid attribute for a block" is an open issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/62151